# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error, no line reference

Tags: c, error-handling

I am receiving the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. This code was working earlier, and I am at a lost what is causing this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. This error provides no line reference either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int assignX(int nCol, int nRow, double *Xflat, char *fileName);

int main(){
   FILE *f;
   char myStr[1000];
   int strL;
   int nCol;
   int nRow;
   char *fileName = "reg.dat";
   int i, j, k, z, n1=nCol, n2=1, info;

   double *Xflat;
   double *temp;

   f = fopen(fileName, "r");
   if (f == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else {
     if (fgets(myStr, 1000, f) != NULL )
       puts(myStr);
     fclose(f);
   }

   strL = strlen(myStr);
   nCol = 3;
   nRow = 150;
   printf("Sample size and number of predictors are %d and %d respectively.\n", nRow, nCol-1);

   assignX(nCol, nRow, Xflat, fileName);

   return 0;
}

int assignX(int nCol, int nRow, double *Xflat, char *fileName){
  int i=0;
  int j;
  int k=0;
  char string[1000];
  char* data = NULL;
  FILE *f;
  f = fopen(fileName, "r");

  while(fgets(string, sizeof(string), f) != NULL){
    data = strtok(string, " ");
    for (j=0; NULL != data && j<nCol; j++){
        if (data[strlen(data) - 1] == '\n')
            data[strlen(data) - 1] = '\0';

        if (j!=0){
          Xflat[i] = atof(data);
          i++;
        }
        data = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
  }

  for (i=0;i<(nRow*(nCol-1));i++){
    printf("%f\n", Xflat[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it through a debugger?

Comment: Hint: use `-g` option with `gcc` and try running the binary using `gdb`. It produces a lot of useful information.

Comment: this code block: 'if (f == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");' also needs to call 'exit()' otherwise the code, after outputing the verbiage from perror() will continue execution after the closing brace '}' of the IF code block

Comment: regarding this line: 'f = fopen(fileName, "r");'  always check the returned value from fopen() (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: there can be, at most, one newline in the read string.  Therefore the check for a newline should be before entering the loop, even before the first call to strtok().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, you're using `double *Xflat;` uninitialized. Accessing uninitalized memory invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in turn *may* cause segmantation fault.

You need to allocate memory to `double *Xflat;` before using it.

*A Suggestion: Enable `-g` flag while compiling and run your binary through a debugger like `gdb`. Most of the time in pinpoints the error to the specific line number itself.*

Answer (score 2):

```
   if (j!=0){
       Xflat[i] = atof(data);
       i++;
        }
```

Here `Xflat` is uninitialized and you are trying to write to some memory which is not allocated so the behavior is undefined and you need to allocate memory for your pointer before writing something to it.

Answer (score 0):

in function assignX(),

the passed parameters nRow and nCol are arbitrary/hardcoded values that have nothing to do with the actual input file contents.

```
Therefore, the code block beginning with 
'for (i=0;i<(nRow*(nCol-1));i++){'  
 has nothing to do with the number of entries 
 saved in the Xflat[] array.

 Therefore, the printf() will either not print all the Xflat[] entries
 or 
 will print from uninitialized memory, 
 resulting in undefined behaviour 
 and can/will lead to a seg fault event. 

suggest: 
1) do not pass the xRow and xCol variables
2) use for( int j=0; j<i; j++ )

There is also the problem that the 'double *Xflat'
does not point to any valid/allocated memory.

suggest:  in main()
double * Xflat = NULL;

and in the assignX() function,
use realloc() and the value 'i+1' 
before each setting of any Xflat[i] offset to a value
which will result in many (expensive) calls to realloc()
An alternative method would be only call realloc()
when all the available 'double' slots are filled
and realloc() use double the current number of 'double' slots
(remembering that the size value would be: sizeof double * numberSlots)

Also, the pointer Xflat is not used anywhere in main() 
so suggest removing from main and from the assignX parameter list
the Xflat declaration can be moved to the assignX function

the main variable 'temp' is not used, so should be eliminated
the main variable 'strL' is only set, but not used
    so should be eliminated

there are some other problems, 
enable all the warnings when compiling.  Then fix the warnings.
```